# Trying to fetch shopItems from json file

Tags: json, swift

Hey im trying to fetch jsonData from url and parse it to [String : [ShopItem]] Dictionary but second day is going and i didnt make success. can u help pls)

thats this URL: let latestURL = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/cc0071a1-f06e-48fa-9e90-b1c2a61eaca7")

```
struct ShopItem: Codable {
    let category: String
    let name: String
    let price: Int
    let image_url: String
}

public class NetworkHelper {
    
    var items: [ShopItem] = []
    
    
    let latestURL = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/cc0071a1-f06e-48fa-9e90-b1c2a61eaca7")
    let flashSaleURL = URL(string: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/a9ceeb6e-416d-4352-bde6-2203416576ac")
    
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    
    func downloadLatest(_ completion: () -> Void) {
        
        guard let latestURL = latestURL else {
            fatalError()
        }
        
            let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: latestURL) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      (200..<300).contains(httpResponse.statusCode),
                      let self = self else {
                    fatalError()
                }
                guard let data = data else {
                    fatalError()
                }
               
               
                    if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String : [ShopItem]].self, from: data) {
                        self.items = results["latest"]!
                    } else {
                        fatalError("hello idiot")
                    }
            }
        task.resume()
        completion()
        }
    }
}
```

I expected items to place in my created Dictionary but this doesnt seem to work, im jun and mb im waisting some tiny thing.

Comment: Unrelated but you can avoid to become an *idiot* by `catch`ing and `print`ing the Decoding error.

Comment: ty for attention to details) i understand i need do-catch)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [json4swift](https://www.json4swift.com/) to prepare models. You can use [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/) too.

**Note** : price variable you will need to change to Double and not Int. Converter convert to Int because you give integer data.

So using above below will be model.

```
struct ShopModel : Codable {
    var latest : [Latest]?
}

struct Latest : Codable {
    var category : String?
    var name : String?
    var price : Double?
    var image_url : String?
}
```

Now while parsing you will say as below & we are done.

```
if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ShopModel.self, from: data) {
    self.items = results.latest ?? [Latest]()
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks alot ill try this and give a feedback)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : Let error handling by him only. I just point him to main error... regarding optional I prefer to keep all optional as api developer can give any variable as null... **I simply don't trust web-developers**

Comment: sorry, now I don't understand how do I get image to this model (I need to show item's image in collectionView cell with its name and price.

Comment: @максиммартынов : That is another question... post another and we will give answer there... mark this as accepted if this helped...

Comment: I guess I need ViewModel class for this that will replace ShopModel and will get image from url?

Comment: @максиммартынов : You have `items` as your `Latest` list. so `items[0]. price ?? 0.0` will give you price of first object...